Forwarding the data from client to game servers based on dns name passed from the client
Basically I have a number of udp game servers I want to load balance/proxy based on the dns name passed when the player connects to the server.
For example I have 3 game servers s1 s2 and s3. The proxy server should route the traffic based on the configuration, like if the dns is s1.domain.com, it should select server1 same for s2 and s3. So are there any loadbalancers/proxy that can do this kind of job?
And also one more question is that when sending data to server from clients does udp contains the dns information or just the IP which is resolved from the dns server?
I tried running nginx using ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module from nginx. But it didn't work for me. I tried to configure Envoy, but skipped it because of the amount of configuration it requires.

Given that these are UDP servers I doubt that they use TLS. But no TLS used means that any attempts to extract the DNS name from the non-existing TLS handshake will fail.
